# Using special characters in an Android application package name

Tags: java, android, package

I have been following along on this beginner's tutorial (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project) on Android application development to help me create my first Android application.

For the "Configure your project" window, the tutorial suggests using "com.example.myfirstapp" as a package name. Obviously, my real app would not be called "myfirstapp", and it is not restricted to ".com" (can be ".io" or ".org" as well), but this is just an example.

Let's say that I design an app called "Application XY". When I use a version control system, such as Git, I would name the repository "application-xy". I usually make use of the free tier of GitHub Pages, which allows organization sites with the URL structure: "https://application-xy.github.io/".

I was thinking of using the above URL as a package name for my Android application, but I wanted to make sure that Android and Java will not throw any errors if I name my application package "io.github.application-xy" (the special character in question is a dash "-", but this could also apply to asterisks "*", pound signs "#", etc.).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Java package name is a sequence of simple identifiers separated by dots.

Each simple identifier is made up of Java letters and Java digits (these are not limited to just the letters and digits in US ASCII).

Underscore is allowed in Java 8 though I've heard rumours it's being deprecated.

Hyphen/dash/etc. are not allowed.

[Link to Java language spec for package names.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4)

[Link to Java language spec for identifiers.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-Identifier)

Comment: Thanks! So I guess I'll name my repository "applicationxy" instead of "application-xy".